# How fast is the area of rectangle increasing?

Tags: calculus

The length of a rectangle is increasing at a rate of 8 cm/s and
its width is increasing at a rate of $3$ cm/s . When the length is
20 cm and the width is 10 cm, how fast is the area of the rectangle
increasing?

So on internet I found a solution but I didn't do that way and I am still thinking that I am not wrong but the answer is not the same. I am gonna write both the solutions which I found on int and by myself and I will be waiting your help.

Which I found on the int: 
$A=lw$  then take derivative $\frac{dA}{dt}= \frac{dl}{dt}.w + l.\frac{dw}{dt}$

using given number $\frac{dA}{dt}= (8)(10) + (20)(3)$

My answer: given numbers--> $\frac{dl}{dt}= 8$,   $\frac{dw}{dt}=3$,  $l=20$, $w =10$

so $A=wl$  when I wanna write $w$ in terms of $l$ ----> $l=2w$

so $A=2w*w$ when I take derivative of it ---> $\frac{dA}{dw}= 4w $

according to chain rule $\frac{dA}{dt}= \frac{dA}{dw}\frac{dw}{dt}$

when I put the numbers ----> $4w*3$ and we know that $w=10$

It should be 120. I think I found my mistake but still couldn't understand why. I write $w$ in terms of l but if I do the other way then the result is 160. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why isn't it $8*3 = 24$. If the area is $lw$ then the area after a second will be $(8l)(3w) = 24wl$ and so on. am I missing something?

Comment: $l$ is twice $w$ only at that particular time and it's *not* a general functional relationship between these two values.

Comment: Your expression for $\frac{dA}{dt}$ is correct. It should be $140$.

Comment: @Yanko, $8$ and $3$ are rates of increase of each size of the rectangle. So your expression is not correct. The rate of increase of the area is correctly $$\frac{dA}{dt} = w\frac{dl}{dt} + l\frac{dw}{dt}$$.

Comment: @Yanko after one second the area is $(l+8)(w+3)$.  Not $(8l)(3w)$.

Comment: Thank u guys so much. And especially thank u @Matteo. I thought the only at particular stuff, too but I wasn't sure so thanks.

Comment: You are taking $w$ and $l$ to be functions of time.  Not constants.  So at this moment in time, $t_0$ we have $l(t_0) = 20 = 2*10 = 2*w(t_0)$ but in general $l(t) \ne 2 w(t)$. And indeed in one second you will have $l = 28$ and $w = 13$ and $28 \ne 2*13$.

Comment: Hem, $8\cdot 10+20\cdot3=140$.

Comment: $l$ and $w$ do not grow proportionally, that's the reason.

Comment: @fleablood so what I understand is if it would be 2w=l in general then my step would be right but since it is at the particular time my step is wrong, right? And they are changing at different rates of course.

Comment: If $2w(t) = l(t)$ then $l$ growing at $8$ inches per second and $w$ growing at $3$ would not be possible.  However if $l$ grew and $8$ inches per second and $w$ grew at $4$ then you could do that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One millisecond later, the sides are $20.008$ and $10.003$ and the relation $l=2w$ is no more true.

The rate of increase of the area must be close to

$$\frac{20.008\cdot10.003-20\cdot10}{10^{-3}}=140.024.$$

With one microsecond, we get

$$\frac{20.000008\cdot10.000003-20\cdot10}{10^{-6}}=140.000024.$$

This confirms the answer $140$.

The reason why your method doesn't work is because

$$\frac{20}{10}\ne\frac{8}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that at this moment in time $A = 2w^2 = 200$
The length and width are not changing uniformly.

If they were then it would be correct to say $A = 4w \frac {dw}{dt}$

But as they are changing at different rates, you need to use the chain rule.

Perhaps a visualization will help.

[image]

We have the rectangle at time $t$ and at time $t+1$ and and the red and green rectangles are the approximate change at some intermediate time.

the green areas sum to $l (dw)$ and red areas $w (dl)$

Comment: thank you! I think I understand now but I can't open the link, I think it's kind of bug. Do you mind uploading the picture another website.

Comment: More precisely, the rates shouldn't be equal but proportional to the respective sides.

Comment: @Disintegrators I thought I had.  Looks fine on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of $l$ and $w$ as functions of time.

$l(t) = L + 8t$ where $L$ is the initial length.  And $w(t) = W+3t$ and, yes, $\frac {dl}{dt}=8$ and $\frac {dw}{dt} = 3$ but $l \ne 20$ and $w\ne 10$.  (That'd mean they are constant functions.  They aren't.)  $l(t_0) = 20$ and $w(t_0) = 10$ at time $t_0$.

To make things simple we can let $t_0=0$ and $l(t) = 20 + 8t$ and $w(t) = 10 + 3t$ and $l(0) =20$ and $w(0) = 10$.

Now we just can't say $l(t) = 2w(t)$ because that just isn't true.  You could say $ {l(t)} = \frac {20+8t}{10+3t}{w(t)}$ and $A(t) =  \frac {20+8t}{10+3t}{w(t)}^2$ but... that just makes things complicated.  (If I had more time and energy I'd be curious to try to figure that and see if it is the same but.... I don't.)